# Benchmark an Truecrypt-encrypted HDD

Tags: hard-drive, performance, encryption, truecrypt, benchmarking

I have a TrueCrypt encrypted Disk (Full Disk encryption of a non-system Partition), which looks like this while being mounted:

[image: true]

Question is: What happens when I try to benchmark this HDD using HDTune? Because in HDTune (left hand side of the following screenshot) I can only select the disk, not the mounted drive. So into which section/sectors will HDTune try to write into and what happens than to my TrueCrypt volume? Will it become un-decryptable? As you can see, at least in CrystalDiskMark I can select the concrete drive-letter, so I can choose the mounted drive, meaning the benchmark will bench the combination of HDD-speed and encryption speed, which is not really representing the HDD speed, but it's better than nothing, and my i7 4770K should anyhow be fast enough I suppose.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I know, I did do the benchmark before the FDE. "If you write data to your volume, you absolutely will be able to decrypt it, not that any data that HDTune writes is permanent." It was just not clear to me where exactly HDTune will write the data to, independently on whether it is a small or big amount of data. If the disk is fully encrypted, there's no space left for HDTune to write to, isn't it? And it cannot know the "format" of the drive, so it cannot simply write into any raw space?

Comment: `You have mounted a partition on the drive, as J within the operating system, which means HDTune has the ability to write data to it.`. Wait, this is exactly part of my question. CrystalDiskMark shows the drive as `J` so will write to it. Yes, this I know and this wont break my FDE. But HDTune shows the drive by its name, independently from whether I mounted it as J or not. If not mounted, it's still shown like this in HDTune. Hence in this case I wasnt sure into which areas it'd write to... So even dismounting the drive, HDTune shows it. Where will it write to then?

Comment: I dont think HDTune *knows* anything about the drive being mounted or not. Hence my question

Comment: Does HDTune show any other storage device as the drive letter instead of the device name?  It's been years since I used that tool, I would imagine the different in the UI, would mean you have to configure where the data is written to (on the drive).  At the end of the day the device HDTune is listing is the same size as the partition you have mounted.  If you unmount the drive, my experience indicates, HDTune would be unable to write anything to the storage device.

Comment: Alright, the latter would make sense (*If you unmount the drive, my experience indicates, HDTune would be unable to write anything to the storage device*). I havent yet tried because I was scared on where it would write to. But yes, it doesn't list any drive letters apart from the device name, but I'll check whether there is a specific setting in HDTune which gives me this option. Thanks as of now.